# Display a string from database for each day of the year in HTML

Tags: playframework-2.0

Maybe this is a stupid and naive question, but I want to display a String ( Daily quotes) on my webpage. Im using Play 2.0.4 with Postgres 9.1. I want a little help on

1. The best way to implement/create the table which contains a unique String for each day of the year i.e 365 quotes for 365 days.
2. The controller program which reads/pulls the quotes from the DB

Comment: Can you provide more info about what you're trying to do? Are you asking how to set up the database or how to pull content from an existing db?

Comment: Sorry! The hyphen(-) that I used as bullet for my 2 questions didn't come out as I thought. Yes I would like to know 1.How to set up the database and 2.How to pull content from the DB.

Comment: Are you working in java or scala?

Comment: Ok, looking at the Play 2.1 docs, it looks like for your question, the base language doesn't matter. I have a couple more questions though. First, where are your quotes coming from?  If you want them to be key sentences from blog posts, you should add a form field to the posting page where the author can paste his/her best quotable. If you just want to write these yourself, there's not much need for a database. You could just write a static page of quotes.

Comment: Its java. Yep, the quotes are mine. But won't the static page's file size be a deterrent? And also how do i display a quote for a different each day?